# Add an include to each module of a Qt project

Tags: c++, qt, include, qmake, projects-and-solutions

Is there a portable way to add certain include(s) to all C++ modules that are part of a Qt project by modifying the .pro file (like I would do it for GCC using the `-include` option)?

Comment: I think you need to clarify, honestly it is very unclear. gcc can be used to compile a Qt project,(and others c++ compilers). So .pro file is part of the build tool of Qt, it is more to be compare with makefile... 
What do you want to do ?

Comment: I want to add a header to all project modules using a Qt project option (instead of a `#include "myheader.h"` instruction in every module).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's no portable way to do this, as every compiler should be treated differently.

The best you can do is to write a bunch of conditionals. For example

```
*-g++:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -include myheader.h
else:*-msvc:QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -Fi myheader.h
# else:...
```